# play music in background java

Tags: java, audio, background

I created "SimplePlayer" that plays music but it stops my app. I want a solution for the audio and my application ( Jframe type ) work in the same time here is my class:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import javazoom.jl.player.Player;

public class SimplePlayer {
    public SimplePlayer() {
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/Admin/Music/B.B. King - Blues Boys Tune - YouTube.mp3");
            Player playMP3 = new Player(fis);
            playMP3.play();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try to include the code in a `new Thread(){}.start();`? (Edit : I upvoted so that you get enough points to be able to reply in comments)

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle The OP can always post comments on their own posts, they don't need reputation for that.

Comment: no , i didn't i just type "SimplePlayer s=new SimplePlayer();" in the app constructor

Comment: @J.Steen Seems logical but I did not know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the Player code in a new Thread then start it :

```
new Thread() {

  @Override
  public void run() {
    //As your stream implements Closeable, it is better to use a "try-with-resources"
    try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/Admin/Music/B.B. King - Blues Boys Tune - YouTube.mp3")){
      new Player(fis).play();
    }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
  }
}.start();
```